# Basic use of node-installed component (eg datepicker)

Tags: node.js, vuejs3

I want to use a [vue3 datepicker component](https://icehaunter.github.io/vue3-datepicker/#installation). However, I can't seem to get it started.

After installing datepicker using `npm -i vue3-datepicker`, I entered the supplied code into a local html file:

```
<script setup>
import Datepicker from '../src/datepicker/Datepicker.vue'
import { ref } from 'vue'
const picked = ref(new Date())

</script>

<template>
  <datepicker v-model="picked" />
</template>
```

I saved and opened the file, but the code doesn't seem to do anything.

The example code doesn't even have an input element to connect the calendar to.

The error from the Chrome console is

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

How can I get a datepicker up and running? What am I missing? Can someone help with a more complete example (totally working code?)

Comment: I don't know how to "build" it..?

Comment: Can you describe what you want to achieve? What is your environment/project setup? My first answer in a Vue.js 3 environment was downvoted. So what am I missing?